# Google Maps Javascript Route From your Location to Clicked Marker on Web

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to create a route between my current location and clicked marker's location in Google Maps Web, however I couldn't find such a thing is there any example of it or we can only do it in Google Maps Android or iOS.

PS: I was able to handle it in HereMaps Last year, it is quite funny if Google Maps doesn't have that feature.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple) Google Maps tutorial will help

Comment: yeah I've seen it but I couldn't transfer select options into markers :) okay thanks anyway I will try to go on from that one!.